# Edited value does not change while updating in website

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

My scenario is as follows.

I'm using ASP.NET 2.0 and VB.NET.

I have a login page. If I am an existing user, when I log in, my user details are popped in the respective textBoxes. Now I wish to change one of these fields. I edited one and then clicked on the Edit button to update the record. It's not updated but instead it brings the existing value from the text box.

How can I achieve this?

```
 DBCmd.CommandText = "update IOMFNewMember set FirstName=@FirstName,MiddleName=@MiddleName,LastName=@LastNa,Gender=@Gender,DateofBirth=@DateofBirth,MartialStatus=@MartialStatus,DateofWedding=@DateofWedding,Nationality=@Nationality,ResidenceCountry=@ResidenceCountry,DateofJoiningIOMf=@DateofJoiningIOMf,EmailId=@EmailId,mobileno=@mobileno,AtPresent=@AtPresent,familykuwait=@familykuwait,DateofDeath =@DateofDeath where UserName=@Entery and MemberID=@MemberID"
```

Comment: What is the code behind the edit button? Do you really hit that SQL query? Does the SQL query evaluate to what you wanted to have? Why don't you try debugging?

Comment: I have tried debugging   DBCmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtName.Text. This value brings the existing value that is in Database

Comment: This means, when you change something in the form and post it, it does not reach the code behind. Only the original values are there. You may show the code behind the Edit button.

Comment: DBCmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value =txtName.Text. ra = DBCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement you have to run a sql command same as that u are using to populate the textboxes with the user details.
That is supposing you are using this in the login button click event

```
  string strSql="select * from customers where id=" + txtLoginId.Text;
  SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection(strCon); 
  con.Open();

  SqlDataAdapter da=new SqlDataAdapter();
  da.SelectCommand=new SqlCommand(strSql,con);
  DataSet dset=new DataSet();
  da.Fill(dset);
  con.Close();
```

You will have to use this in the edit button click event :

```
string strSql="update EmployeeTable set password = '" + txtPassword.Text + "'";
SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection(strCon); 
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand(strsql, con);
cmd.ExecuteScalar();
con.Close();
```

Hope this will clear you confusion.
This is just an example. For a real time situation its advisable to use stored procedures only for any database query.